# averaging across elements in a 3-D array in R

Tags: r, for-loop, multidimensional-array, apply

I want to get average values from a list where each element is a 3-D array.

Example, where ind1 represents an element in a 3-D array:

```
>data$ind1
    , , rep1

              [,1]       [,2]     [,3]
     [1,] 58.93456  6.3580551 269.8844
     [2,] 70.88502 -3.4082403 269.6049
     [3,] 75.86015  2.0126083 264.9410

    , , rep2

              [,1]       [,2]     [,3]
     [1,] 58.94869  6.3872151 269.9296
     [2,] 71.04539 -3.4487939 269.5489
     [3,] 75.85713  2.1556785 265.0365

    , , rep3
              [,1]       [,2]     [,3]
     [1,] 59.04455  6.3075519 269.8789
     [2,] 71.04752 -3.4541416 269.6695
     [3,] 74.74456  1.9712155 265.3075
```

For one element:

```
>apply(data$ind1, c(1, 2), mean)    
              [,1]       [,2]     [,3]
     [1,] 58.96706  6.3587708 269.8968
     [2,] 71.00619 -3.4402599 269.5941
     [3,] 75.57361  2.0459055 265.0593
```

Across many elements, where each element has anywhere from 2-4 reps:

```
>for(i in data) {
  apply(data[i], c(1, 2), mean) 
}
```

Am I on the right track? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, you want to `apply` the `mean` function (just as you're doing) to each element of a list (each element happens to be an array).

The efficient way to do this is with `lapply`:

```
# example data
mylist <- list(
    two   = array(runif(2^3), dim=c(2,2,2)),
    three = array(runif(3^3), dim=c(3,3,3)),
    four  = array(runif(4^3), dim=c(4,4,4))
)

# solution
lapply(mylist, apply, c(1,2), mean)
```

Because `mean` does not care how big that third array dimension is, it doesn't matter how many `ind`'s you have; it will average over however many are there.

Comment: That did the job. Thank you!